# Can Exception.Data be null in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

For years I've had the faint memory that in C# the property `Exception.Data` can be `null` for some very specific exceptions (but I can't remember which). I've even built some extension methods to help around this problem. However, I just tried to find some documentation on this problem but couldn't find any.

Could it be that this was a thing some years ago (in an older .NET Framework version) but is no longer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the documentation I was remembering. It's in the ".NET Framework 4" offline help in Visual Studio (2017). Here the documentation for `Exception.Data` contains an additional note:

> The `ExecutionEngineException`, `OutOfMemoryException`, `StackOverflowException` and `ThreadAbortException` classes always return **null** for the value of the **Data** property.

Interestingly the [online help for `Exception.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data) is missing this note - but otherwise its contents seem to be the same as the offline help.

**Update:** I filed an issue for this inconsistency: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/4045